# Meteor react render subscribe

Tags: reactjs, meteor

How i can make the PostList class component render from subscribe,I really dont get the withtracker function,I googled and I found different versions but I cant figure it out to make it work,what Im doing wrong and how should i do it?I did rerad the documentation but it didn't helped much,please explain me.

react-meteor-data package

```
this is my mongo db.posts.find()
{ " _id " : ".." , " data " :{ " title " : " s " , " description " : "a" }, " userid " : "..." , " createdat ":131231}

my publish Meteor.publish("postlist",function(){
return Posts.find({});
})

my react component 
export default class PostList extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return{

        }
    }
}

withTracker((props) => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('postlist');

    return {
        loading: !handle.ready(),
        posts: Posts.find().fetch()
    }
}, PostList)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to export the newly created component from `withTracker`, not the `PostList` itself.

Also `withTracker` is a HOC wich returns a function you need the component to wrap with.

```
class PostList extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return {
            <div>Some content</div>
        }
    }
}

export default withTracker((props) => {
    const handle = Meteor.subscribe('postlist');

    return {
        loading: !handle.ready(),
        posts: Posts.find().fetch()
    }
})(PostList)
```